# Crop phone screen using contour

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to crop phone screen given on the image. I tried this code but the result is not what i wanted. 
**[Phone Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTE70.jpg)**
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('phone_test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_, contours, _= cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])

crop = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('phone_test_crop.jpg',crop)
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('image',img) #show the image
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result would be just this
**[Crop Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2V3P.jpg)**
[image]

any solutions?

Comment: well, you basically are saying that anything that is not pure black (in jpg, you will be surprise with the result :) ) should be used in the contour algorithm. Have you taken a look to your `thresh` image? you probably want a way higher value to isolate the screen from everything else. You may also get the borders of the phone so you may get more than one contour.... you only check the contour number 0... you could even check if that is the correct contour you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to the problem.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

# read and scale down image
img = cv2.pyrDown(cv2.imread('sample_images/phone_test.jpg', 
cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))

# threshold image
ret, threshed_img = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),
            150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# find contours and get the external one
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(threshed_img, 
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
    # get the bounding rect
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    crop = img[y:y+h+22,x:x+w+5] #give a bit of space, because the boundingRect is not perfect

cv2.imwrite('sample_images/phone_test_crop.jpg', crop)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Before: 
[Before crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjPkF.jpg)

After:
[After crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZHN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the code which I made and worked for me.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('phone.jpg')
# cv2.imshow('image', img)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of blue color in HSV
lower = np.array([20, 20, 20])
upper = np.array([220, 220, 220])

# Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
# cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

kernel = np.ones((1, 10), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
# cv2.imshow('dilated', img_dilation)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

# find contours
im2, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

    # Getting ROI
    roi = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    # show ROI
    # cv2.imshow('segment no:'+str(i), roi)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 0), 1)  # put (0,255,0) to see green rectangles
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    if h > 100 and 350 < w < 450:
        # cv2.imshow('marked areas', img)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)

        # cv2.imshow('roi', roi)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)

        cv2.imwrite('extracted_screen.png', roi)
```

Is up to you tweak the code to fit specific needs (ex: more or less precision on screen extraction).

**Result**

[image: extracted_screen]
[image: res2]

Comment: i tried the code but it is not working. i found another solution